# Php comments script

Tags: php, mysql, database, comments

Anyone know where I can find a simple comments script in php/mysql, i just want a system that has the basic font enhancements, url links, image and reply functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These seem to fit the bill

http://www.scriptsmill.com/comments_demo.html

http://www.gentlesource.com/comment-script/

http://www.digitalmidget.com/php_noob/comment.php

The second is not **free** as in **free beer** however. The first one looks alright.

I just googled "php"+"page-comments"+"script"

Comment: Thanks John T. I must have drunk that before sending :)

Answer (score 0):

I will add the Commentics to the list, because it has many features, and it is free -

[Simple Comment Rate Script](http://www.commentics.org/demo-menu.php)